Safe way to export the context value key?
I heard that should keep the context value key private and provide getter/setter for accessing the value outside the package, like this:
type contextKey int

const (
    requestIDKey contextKey = iota
    otherKey
)

func ContextWithRequestID(ctx context.Context, requestID string) context.Context {
    return context.WithValue(ctx, requestIDKey, requestID)
}

func RequestIDFromContext(ctx context.Context) string {
    requestID, ok := ctx.Value(requestIDKey).(string)
    if ok {
        return requestID
    }
    return ""
}

However today I encountered how golang defines the ServerContextKey:
type contextKey struct {
    name string
}

var (
    ServerContextKey = &contextKey{"http-server"}
    LocalAddrContextKey = &contextKey{"local-addr"}
)

The keys are exported, so does it mean we can export the context value key and let other packages to retrieve the value from context object directly with context.WithValue(ctx, ServerContextKey, localvar)? Is it a recommend way since golang itself implements in this way?
Thanks.

Keeping the key unexported and Setting/Getting the values through exported functions is a nice way to hide unimportant details. However if you need to or want to provide more control to the calling code by exporting the key(s) then that's fine as well, there's no formal rule against that.

@mkopriva thanks, but the type of the key should never be exported, correct?
